# Equations of motion for controlled/driven classical systems? Does D'Alembert's principle apply?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I'm puzzled about how to derive the equations of motion for certain classical systems where some entity is controlling some of the DOFs.

For example, consider a double-pendulum, with lengths $l_1$ and $l_2$, masses $m_1$ and $m_2$, and which deviate from the vertical by $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$.  Let's say that at the joint between the two pendulums (pendula?), there is a little device controlling the angle $\theta_1+\pi-\theta_2$, and forces it to be some function of time: $\theta_1(t)+\pi-\theta_2(t)=g(t)$.  If I understand correctly, this is a holonomic constraint, since it is simply a functional relationship between the DOFs and t.  Obviously the position and velocities of the masses can then be expressed just in terms of $\theta_1(t)$, $g(t)$, and their derivatives. 
My question is: can we then determine the equation of motion for $\theta_1$ with the Euler-Lagrange equations in the "usual" way?  The reason I have doubts here is that it seems like the Euler-Lagrange equations come from D'Alembert's principle, where the constraints do no "virtual work" on the system; and I'm not sure the constraint in this case satisfies this.